# Once off payment with Stripe using the API ID

Tags: stripe-payments

I have created a subscription service using Stripe. I can subscribe a user to use recurring payments. This is the relevant code (node):

```js
  // Create the subscription
  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: req.body.customerId,
    items: [{ price: req.body.priceId }],
    expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
  });
```

This works and uses the `priceId` as shown in the dashboard:

[image]

However, it falls over when I sell a product which isn't recurring. I get the error:

```
The price specified is set to `type=one_time` but this field only accepts prices with `type=recurring`
```

I understand the error, but I am not sure if I can set a subscription to not be recurring.

My app has 3 tiers:

- once off
- monthly
- yearly

Ideally, I would like not to add a whole new section of code to handle what seems like a subset of what subscriptions do, but even if I do, the `paymentIntent` object seems to only take an amount rather than the API ID as shown in the picture. Is there any way to do this using the infrastructure I have already built?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't create a subscription with a non-recurring price, instead for one-off payments you'd use a PaymentIntent.

Prices are meant for use with subscriptions and the Checkout product, but you can still use the data in them for PaymentIntents. For instance:

```js
// get the price 
const price = await stripe.prices.retrieve(req.body.priceId);

// check if the price is recurring or not
if (price.recurring !== null) {
  // Create the subscription
  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: req.body.customerId,
    items: [{ price: req.body.priceId }],
    expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
  });

  // do something with the subscription

} else {
  const pi = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    customer: req.body.customerId,
    currency: 'usd',
    amount: price.unit_amount,
  });
 
  // do something with the PaymentIntent
}
```

Comment: If need in our server side response, we can add priceId in paymentIntents.create query with 'metadata' param. (For futur readers like me that need it)

Answer (score 1):

you can also attach one-time items via the `subscription.create` call by placing them in `add_invoice_items`.

see: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=node#create_subscription-add_invoice_items